# How do I make a generic handler for Toggle for setState in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I want to make a generic handler for setstate rather than having two different handlers? How can I do that?

I am thinking of something like:

```
  setStateHandler= (stateToBeChanged) =>{
    this.setState({
      stateToBeChanged: !this.state.stateToBeChanged
    });
  }
```

```
  handleHappyToggle = () =>{
    this.setState({
      Happy: !this.state.Happy
    });
  }

  handleSadToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      Sad: !this.state.Sad
    });
  }
```

My two touchable opacities:

```
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={this.handleHappyToggle}
>
<Text> {this.state.happy ? 'Yes' : 'No' } </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
onPress={this.handleSadToggle}
>
<Text> {this.state.sad? 'Yes' : 'No' } </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** added demo StackSnippet...

***EDIT 2:*** added 3 total ways to handle this "generically"

You could use a generic handler to accomplish this - just supply the "mood" as a parameter.

```
handleMoodToggle = mood => event => {
    if(!["Happy", "Sad"].includes(mood)){
        return null;
    }
    this.setState({
        [mood]: !this.state[mood]
    })
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleMoodToggle("Happy")}>
    <Text> {this.state.happy ? 'Yes' : 'No'} </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleMoodToggle("Sad")}>
    <Text> {this.state.sad ? 'Yes' : 'No'} </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

---

***DEMO:***

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    Happy: true,
    Sad: false
  };

  handleMoodToggle1 = mood => event => {
    if (!["Happy", "Sad"].includes(mood)) {
      return null;
    }
    this.setState({
      [mood]: !this.state[mood]
    })
  };
  
  handleMoodToggle2 = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.innerHTML]: !this.state[event.target.innerHTML]
    });
  }
  
  handleMoodToggle3 = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: !this.state[event.target.name]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleMoodToggle1("Happy")}>Toggle Happy</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleMoodToggle1("Sad")}>Toggle Sad</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleMoodToggle2}>Happy</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleMoodToggle2}>Sad</button>    
        <br />
        <button name="Happy" onClick={this.handleMoodToggle3}>Happy 3</button>
        <button name="Sad" onClick={this.handleMoodToggle3}>Sad 3</button> 
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is I wanted a generic handler for setstate? that takes a parameter?

Comment: @William That is a generic handler... How else do you expect the handler to know the difference between 'Happy' or 'Sad'??? Just because there is a parameter does not mean it isn't "generic"... This allows you to easily reuse the same handler for multiple purposes...

Comment: @William I just added 2 more examples of how you could handle this "generically" and WITHOUT parameters..... regardless of how you handle this, the handler method HAS to know which property you wish to target in state....

Comment: @William the example you added to your question `setStateHandler` is literally, EXACTLY what my first example demonstrated.... your `setStateHandler` example has a parameter....... what are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

you can check my exmaple for you:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    emotions: [
      { name: 'happy', status: true },
      { name: 'sad', status: false },
      { name: 'angry', status: true },
    ]
  }
  handleEmotionToggle = (index) => {
    let emotions = [...this.state.emotions]
    emotions[index].status = !emotions[index].status
    this.setState({
      emotions
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.emotions.map((emotion, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity key={index}
                onPress={()=>this.handleEmotionToggle(index)}
              >
                <Text style={{margin:10,fontSize:20}}>{emotion.name} - {emotion.status ? "YES":"NO"} </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```